# How to take Screenshot of Website with Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I use vim and Firefox + Vimperator, now I want to be able to create page screenshots with Vimperator by a single Vimperator command to create a thumbnail of websites later.

Vimperator seems to not have a screenshot functionality. I know you can do it through the debugger or the developer Toolbar using `Shift+F2` to open it and then `screenshot --fullpage` and I even can open the Toolbar using Vimperator, but I didn't manage to input something there.

I tried with the sequence `<S-F2><CR>screenshot`, but after the Toolbar loads, Vimperator already ran all following commands (screenshot) as a sequence in normal mode.

How can I achieve taking website screenshots using a single Vimperator command?

---

**Update:**

I experimented a bit more and almost achieved a workaround using this sequence:

`<S-F2>:js liberator.sleep(300)<CR><S-F2>screenshot --fullpage<CR>` where

- `<S-F2>` opens the Developer Toolbar
- `:js liberator.sleep(300)<CR>` take a break to let firefox load the toolbar (could probably be lower than 300ms)
- `<S-F2>` to again gain focus of the toolbar
- `screenshot --fullpage` just input in the toolbar

The problem that occurs now is that I can not 'enter' with `<CR>` as the toolbar does not recognize any input. Only if I manually enter a whitespace it realizes the screenshot input and lets me 'send' the command.

Of course I am also open to other workarounds not using the Developer Toolbar.